# How to update player rounds

Tags: javascript

I want `rounds` to increase by 1 and then the value updated in rounds_div.innerHTML every time the player clicks on any of the cards displayed. I've initialized `let rounds = 0;`  to begin. However whenever I click on a card, instead of increasing by 1 it automatically jumps to 4 and then stays there. How do I get the number of rounds to increase by 1 every time the card is clicked?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=BioRhyme:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Card Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Card Game</h1> 
    <p>Choose a card and get a random point. <br> First player to get 20 points in the least amount of rounds wins</p>
    
<div class="scoreboard">
    <div class="user-score">Points: 0</div>
    <button>Play Again</button>
    <div class="winner"></div>
    <div class="computer-score">Points: 0</div>
    <div class="rounds">Rounds: 0</div>
</div>

<div class="cards"> 
    <div class="card1">
        <div class="button">
            <img class="card1" src="bluecard.png" height=250px width=250px>
            <div class="overlay1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card2">
        <div class="button">
            <img class="card2" src="bluecard.png" height=250px width=250px>
            <div class="overlay2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card3">
        <div class="button">
            <img class="card3" src="bluecard.png" height=250px width=250px>
            <div class="overlay3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card4">
        <div class="button">
            <img class="card4" src="bluecard.png" height=250px width=250px>
            <div class="overlay4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="numbers">
    <div class="user-numbers">Your numbers: </div>
    <div class="computer-numbers">My numbers: </div>
</div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
// Global variables
const btn = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
const userScore = document.querySelector(".user-score");
const computerScore = document.querySelector(".computer-score");
const userChoice = document.querySelector(".user-choice");
const computerChoice = document.querySelector(".computer-choice");
const userNumbers = document.querySelector(".user-numbers");
const computerNumbers = document.querySelector(".computer-numbers");
const winner_div = document.querySelector(".winner"); 
const rounds_div = document.querySelector(".rounds"); 
const buttonAppear = document.querySelector(".button"); 

// Initialize variables to 0
let total = 0; 
let totalc = 0;
let usertotal = 0;  
let computertotal = 0;
let ranNum = 0;
let ranNumC = 0;
let rounds = 0;
const userArray = [];
const computerArray = [];

btn.forEach(function(button){
    button.addEventListener('click', usergetNumber);
    rounds++
    rounds_div.innerHTML = "Rounds: " + rounds;
});

// Run a randomized number from 1-10 whenever user clicks a button and add it 
// to the previous number and display the new total
function usergetNumber(){
    const ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    usertotal = parseInt(total += ranNum);
    userNumbers.innerHTML = "Your numbers: " + ranNum;

    userArray.push(" " + ranNum);
    userNumbers.innerHTML = "Your numbers: " + userArray;
    
    userScore.innerHTML = "Your total: " + usertotal;
    computergetNumber();
    checkWinner();
};

function computergetNumber(){
    const ranNumC = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    computertotal = parseInt(totalc += ranNumC);
    computerNumbers.innerHTML =  "My numbers:" + " " + ranNumC; 

    computerArray.push(" " + ranNumC);
    computerNumbers.innerHTML = "My numbers: " + computerArray;
    
    computerScore.innerHTML = "My total: " + computertotal;
    
}

function checkWinner(){
    if(usertotal === 20) {
        winner_div.innerHTML = "YOU WIN!"   
    }
    else if(usertotal > 20) {
        winner_div.innerHTML = "Too high!"   
    }
    else{
        winner_div.innerHTML = ""   
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this block of code:

```
btn.forEach(function(button){
    button.addEventListener('click', usergetNumber);
    rounds++
    rounds_div.innerHTML = "Rounds: " + rounds;
});
```

You compute the value of rounds as the number of queries elements with the class ‘button’.
I would recommend removing `rounds++`  and `rounds_div.innerHTML = "Rounds: " + rounds;`  from the above block and adding it to `usergetNumber` function.